# TypeScript Named Tuple - Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2345)

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, typechecking

I'm trying to utilize a named tuple *(in this instance `AnniversaryPropertyConfig`)* to describe a function argument in the following simplified code.

```
interface AnniversaryParameters {
    value?: 'date-and-or-time' | 'text';
    altid?: number | string;
    calscale?: 'gregorian';
}

type AnniversaryPropertyConfig = [value: string, parameters?: AnniversaryParameters];

function main(config: AnniversaryPropertyConfig) {
    return config;
}

const config = ['19960415', { value: 'text' as const }];

main(config);
```

However I keep receiving the following error: "Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2345)" I've tried to apply `as const` assertions to the `config` array and its values but to no avail. The error does go away if I typecast the `config` variable to the `AnniversaryPropertyConfig` type. But I feel like this is something that TypeScript should be able to infer without assistance.

For reference a link to an applicable TypeScript Playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIhMAbtAznKATwAUC4BbCSKXZAbwFgAoZV5LOAGwFcIB+AFzIA5ABM4kALRwQoyQHsoksMErDkAHxGQAHmGEBuZm2RcVowchDdyAI2ibkuMFFABzIyzYIuuH534hYTcoCDdFYBlDZgBfZmYwQgAHFHRMHBoCEih5FKhEgGF5EBhgN2QAXmQAbQ4eCCFnVxA3ABpkJLJKalxLNOw8LNIoCio8AF1PZhhuEAQVYuRyOFAACgRi0rchfoz8ImIcvMLNsoBKemM2ULBuKBBkDZKyzzimZifnR9PyqurhACMAE4gQA2AAMABYAQBWYTtOjsLi8IK6fSmWifMDIGKTeJMZZrJ5bM4GIA).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you defined `AnniversaryPropertyConfig` as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) : `[value: string, parameters?: AnniversaryParameters]`

Arrays are never infered as tuple, so you have to explicitly assert the type.

```
interface AnniversaryParameters {
    value?: 'date-and-or-time' | 'text';
    altid?: number | string;
    calscale?: 'gregorian';
}

type AnniversaryPropertyConfig = [value: string, parameters?: AnniversaryParameters];

function main(config: AnniversaryPropertyConfig) {
    return config;
}

const config: AnniversaryPropertyConfig = ['19960415', { value: 'text' }];

main(config);
```

And do yourself a favor, avoid by all means type assertions like `myVar as MyType`. It's never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get rid of the error was to do this:

`const config = ['19960415', { value: 'text' }] as AnniversaryPropertyConfig;`

...or...

`const config: AnniversaryPropertyConfig = ['19960415', { value: 'text' }];`

From what I can guess, TypeScript's type inference sees `['19960415', { value: 'text' }]` as an array that could have strings in any position in the array, or objects that match `{ value: 'text' }` at any position in the array. So the inferred type doesn't have any enforced order for the array elements, making it too broad a type to automatically agree with `AnniversaryPropertyConfig`.